# Extracting several p-values to dataframe column

Tags: r

I have two columns, x=successes, y=total sample.  I want to run binom.test on each of the 30 rows in the df, extract the p-value and store it in a column.  So far this is frustrating all my efforts, and I can't see why.  Example code

```
Pvalues <- data.frame(matrix(ncol=1,nrow=30)) # Creates the dataframe "Pvalues"
names(Pvalues) <- paste0("Pvalues",1:1) # Names the column
head(Pvalues)
Pvalues[Pvalues1] <- with(NewData,binom.test(NumberMeetingTargetAggregate,NumberOfAttendancesAggregate,0.95)$p.value)

error message
Error in binom.test(NumberMeetingTargetAggregate, NumberOfAttendancesAggregate,  : 
  incorrect length of 'x'
```

Comment: `binom.test` is not vectorized, you need a loop for example `Vectorize(binom.test)(x = 1:10, n = 11:20, p = 0.95)['p.value', ] |> unlist()`

Answer (score 0):

you can use apply statement to apply the function on each row.

```
# sample data
df <- data.frame(x = 10:15, y = 20:25)

# apply function to each row
df[['p.value']] <- apply(df, 1, function(row) binom.test(row[1],row[2])$p.value)
df
# x  y   p.value
# 1 10 20 1.0000000
# 2 11 21 1.0000000
# 3 12 22 0.8318119
# 4 13 23 0.6776395
# 5 14 24 0.5412562
# 6 15 25 0.4243562
```